# How to have a dynamic query field in where clause

Tags: javascript, loopback

```
   function check_model_owner(field, value, callback) { 
      Model.find({where: {field: value }}, function(err, models) {
            //code
         });
    }
```

This code is called from two different places, and what follows is the same for both calls.

Of course this breaks now because `field`, in the where clause, does actually not exist in the model, and should be substituted by the `field` variable from the function parameters....can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create the query object:

```
function check_model_owner(field, value, callback) { 
  var query = {};
  query[field] = value;
  Model.find({where: query}, function(err, models) {

  });
}
```